# 404 on Bluemix Toolchains

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, devops-services

I just created a Node.js / Cloudant setup on Bluemix, using the starter kit, and enabled the Continuous delivery toolchain. Git says it is already configured but when I click on it I get a not found (404) error. This is the URL to start git.

https://git.ng.bluemix.net/xxx/xxxxxxx

I am running as the owner of the app and the sample app is running. Am I accessing the correct GIT link?

Answer (score 0):

404 could also mean a credential issue.

Check [this thread](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/370804/gitngbluemixnet-credentials.html) and make sure to use an access token from your own profile page https://git.ng.bluemix.net/profile/personal_access_tokens.